# Azure AD - Inviting Users

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I do not have much experience with AD in general. I have a web app in Azure and I want to authenticate users in the app using Azure AD and I read a bit about Azure AD B2B option but I simply still do not understand it.

What I do now in steps:

1. Create a new Azure Directory
2. In that directory I go to Azure Active Directory (service)
3. Register my application
4. Go to Users/all Users/ New guest user and add the users of the application
5. Job done

What is the difference between me doing this and the Active Directory B2B?

Answer (score 0):

> Azure AD business-to-business (B2B) collaboration capabilities enable any organization using Azure AD to work safely and securely with users from any other organization, small or large. Those organizations can be with Azure AD or without, or even with an IT organization or without. +
>   Organizations using Azure AD can provide access to documents, resources, and applications to their partners, while maintaining complete control over their own corporate data. Developers can use the Azure AD business-to-business APIs to write applications that bring two organizations together in more securely. Also, it's pretty easy for end users to navigate.

Enable users from other organization to access the application is one kind of Azure AD B2B. And the Azure AD B2B is enabled by invite the other users to your organization tenant.

More details bout Azure AD B2B, please refer the link below:

[What is Azure AD B2B collaboration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-what-is-azure-ad-b2b#you-can-easily-add-b2b-collaboration-users-to-your-organization)